# What is the correct syntax for Range.Fomula Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This question might have been answered in other questions but i can't find the correct syntax to use, it is just not working for me...
So i'm trying to put formula in a range of cells with a loop in vba, but the cells where i need to put those formula are dynamically decided :
    Code :

```
Cells(j, (LastColumn + nbVersions2) + 4).Formula = "=IF(" & Cells(5, nbVersionsCat1 + 1) & 
"="""",IF(" & Cells(5, nbVersionsCat1 + 1) & "="""",0,Sheet1!D4),IF('AnotherSheet'!" & 
Cells(5, nbVersionsCat1 + 1) & "="""",Sheet1!C4,1))"
```

So i want to know if the line "IF(" & Cells(5, nbVersionsCat1 + 1) & ".... is the correct syntax to use...

Thank you very much !

Comment: What should the resulting formula be (like if you just typed it manually into the cell)?

Comment: =IF(A5="";IF(B5="";0;Sheet1!D4);IF('AnotherSheet'!B5="";Sheet1!C4;1)) @BigBen

Comment: You need a `.Address` on the end of the `Cells` calls then, otherwise you're using their `.Value`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen !